# SceneKit – Make higher resolution in SCNView

Tags: swift, scenekit, scnview

I am using *SceneKit* and I hate the resolution of the geometry. I read developer documentation and other websites. I found an [article](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnlevelofdetail) on the developer documentation. It gave me this image:

[image: Apples image]

*But couldn't find any information how to do that*, only another **stupid** [article](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scngeometry/1523745-levelsofdetail) on the developer documentation. I really need a higher resolution – it should be smoothed.

[image: My geometry renders by default]

**Is there some one how can help me with this problem?**

Comment: Is that a `SCNTorus`? If so you should increase `ringSegmentCount` and `pipeSegmentCount` to make it "smoother". If it is your own model, then of course *you* are responsible for making it more high-poly.

Comment: Yes, it is an **SCNTorus**, but I want to make a better resolution for every geometry.

Comment: The built-in geometries all have `xxxSegmentCount` properties that you can set. Look at their respective documentation pages for more detail. Does that answer your question?

Comment: I have got one more question: I couldn't find any xxxSegmentCount in SCNText.

Comment: I think `SCNText` automatically uses a more detailed geometry when you zoom in, doesn't it?

Comment: Since OP is asking for explanations: I downvoted because OP didn’t seem to put any effort into understanding how 3D models work or even look at the SCNTorus class reference.

Comment: Sorry, @EmilioPelaez but I didn't understand those properties, and I am not good at searching something in google. My English is really bad, too. And I am bad in swift, because I can write code only after school.

Comment: And you are right, sweeper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the built-in shape geometries have `xxxSegmentCount` properties. You can increase them to make them smoother. Here's a summary table:

| Shape | `segmentCount` properties |
| --- | --- |
| `SCNPlane` | `widthSegmentCount`, `heightSegmentCount`, `cornerSegmentCount` |
| `SCNBox` | `widthSegmentCount`, `heightSegmentCount`, `lengthSegmentCount`, `chamferSegmentCount` |
| `SCNSphere` | `segmentCount` |
| `SCNPyramid` | `widthSegmentCount`, `heightSegmentCount`, `lengthSegmentCount` |
| `SCNCone` | `radialSegmentCount`, `heightSegmentCount` |
| `SCNCylinder` | `radialSegmentCount`, `heightSegmentCount` |
| `SCNCapsule` | `radialSegmentCount`, `heightSegmentCount`, `capSegmentCount` |
| `SCNTube` | `radialSegmentCount`, `heightSegmentCount` |
| `SCNTorus` | `pipeSegmentCount`, `ringSegmentCount` |

You can't control the segment counts for `SCNText` and `SCNShape`, however. Their polygon counts are controlled by SceneKit, but it should always be high enough no matter how zoomed in you are. You shouldn't need to worry about this.

Additional note: The `levelOfDetail` you found is for setting different geometries to use (perhaps with different segment counts) when the camera is a different distance away from the object, to improve performance.

Answer (score 1):

If you've loaded low-poly `.dae` or `.obj` models like `Utah teapot`, you should use the `antialiasing mode` instance property for smoothing faceted surfaces. You can choose between **4 samples** per screen pixel, **2 samples**, or **none**. This will help you load more models, while being smoothed, and not exceed 100K polygons limit.

```
var antialiasingMode: SCNAntialiasingMode { get set }
```

> SceneKit can provide antialiasing, which smooths edges in a rendered scene, using a technique called multisampling. Multisampling renders each pixel multiple times and combines the results, creating a higher quality image at a performance cost proportional to the number of samples it uses.

Real code looks like this:

```
let sceneView = SCNView(frame: .zero)

sceneView.antialiasingMode = .multisampling4X
```

This is a pivot table showing values that available in macOS and iOS.

```
|               macOS                |                iOS               |
|------------------------------------|----------------------------------|
|  .none                             |  .none               (default)   |
|  .multisampling2X                  |  .multisampling2X                |
|  .multisampling4X  (default)       |  .multisampling4X                |
|  .multisampling8X                  |  -                               |
|  .multisampling16X                 |  -                               |
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the geometry you have, you can sub-divide it on the fly.

i.Ex:

```
node.geometry?.subdivisionlevel = 2
```

If your initial geometry is of "good" quality, the result can be astunishing. Give it a try.

Note: it will quadruple your vertices with each incrementation of the sudivision integer. A value of 2 will give you 16 times more vertices than the original geometry contains. This also impacts the memory!